# How to avoid eclipse from changing open files when changing perspective

Tags: eclipse, debugging, perspectives

I'm using Eclipse Neon and am observing annoying behavior that I didn't have with Mars: the list of files that are open in the editor frames changes when I move from C-perspective to debug-perspective. I lose track between perspectives of which files are open where (I use multiple editor frames). Is there a way to disable that specific behavior? I want to keep the behavior of eclipse automatically changing between perspectives when I run the debugger, I just don't want the editor tabs reshuffled in the process.

[C/C++ Perspective -- I have a bunch of files open, represented by editor tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8GZU.png)

[Debug Perspective -- note editors now show only two open tabs, and the ordering is different.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyNEc.png)

EDIT: I discovered this only happens when I use two separate editor frames (i.e., each frame is independently minimizable). When I have two editors inside a single minimizable frame, the tab order is preserved between perspectives.

Comment: I think this is going to need a screenshot. "Editor frame" isn't part of the Eclipse jargon.

Comment: Added screenshots